# Spark ML TrainValidationSplit with predefined train and validation sets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, data-science

The Spark ML class TrainValidationSplit allows me to set the setTrainRatio.  However, I would like to manually create my train and test set. Is there a way I can specify the train and test set in TrainValidationSplit ?

I am using the Scala ML API.

Thanks!

Comment: what would you like to specify exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you can't.

At least in Spark 2.1.1 it is hard-coded that the definition of train and validation data is done via randomSplit:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tuning/TrainValidationSplit.scala#L100-L101

You probably could inherit from the TrainValidationClass and extend the fit function as you see fit.